# setImmediate confusing documentation phrasing

Tags: javascript, node.js

From I've read `setImmediate` adds callback to the end for event loop, while `process.nextTick` adds a callback at the head. But the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args) says the following about `setImmediate`:

> Schedules the "immediate" execution of the callback after I/O events'
>   callbacks and **before timers** created using setTimeout() and
>   setInterval() are triggered.

Yet this example proves that the `setImmediate` adds a callback to the end of the loop regardless of the timers added using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`:

```
function test() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('settimeout');
    }, 5000);

    const start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < 6000) {
        // blocking
    }

    setImmediate(function () {
        console.log('setimmediate');
    });

    process.nextTick(function () {
        console.log('nextTick');
    });
}

test();
```

Outputs:

```
nextTick
settimeout
setimmediate
```

So is documentation wrong or I'm not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Even simpler test case: http://pastebin.com/qG4ADTrL For me, the linked test case outputs the same as your example above, on Node v4, v6, and v7. Have you checked the bug list?

Comment: See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7145, but even if I change the last line to `setTimeout(test, 10);`, I still get an order I don't expect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry, didn't understand - bug list for what?

Comment: For NodeJS, the thing you're having a problem with.

Comment: I see, thanks, I thought it could be the bug in implementation, not documentation :). Or my misunderstanding. Thanks for your help

Comment: :-) Well, if the docs say one thing and the implementation says something else, it's a bug in *one* of them (at least!). BTW, not the only strangeness-probably-bug related to timers in NodeJS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, right, thanks) good luck